# How can I search for a string recursively under the current directory?

Tags: compile-mode

(Note: this will be a wiki-like question in that I already figured out the answer.  I'm posting it here on the hope it might be useful to others...)

How do I search for a string recursively under the current directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the Emacs commands **`find-grep-dired`** and **`find-dired`**. They do pretty much what you are trying to do, I think. And they present the results in a Dired buffer, giving you all of the features of Dired.

(Library [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)) contains enhanced versions of these commands, and puts them in a **Run `find` Command** menu, along with some other `find` commands.)

Comment: `rgrep` may also be of interest.

Comment: M-x find-grep (or grep-find) is now my favorite command.  Thank you for this improvement over my own answer.

Comment: You're welcome. You can find this and lots of other gems in the Emacs manual.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy trick:

```
M-x compile <return>
find . -name "*.[ch]" -exec grep -n YOUR_STRING_HERE {} /dev/null \;
```

(Of course you can select the file types you want rather than `*.[ch]`.)

This kicks off a compilation process.  The -n argument to grep gives you response strings nicely formatted for Compilation mode, e.g.:

```
find . -name "*.[ch]" -exec grep -n assert\\.h {} /dev/null \;
./drivers/fsl_common.h:34:#include <assert.h>
./drivers/fsl_flash.h:35:#include <assert.h>
./source/drivers/common/fsl_common.h:34:#include <assert.h>
./source/drivers/flash/fsl_flash.h:35:#include <assert.h>
./source/utilities/fsl_assert.h:38:#include <assert.h>
./utilities/fsl_shell.c:64:#include <assert.h>
```

This way, you can put your cursor on one of the lines in the Compilation window and hit return -- it will take you to that file and line.

Comment: See the Emacs commands `find-grep-dired` and `find-dired`. (Library [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el) contains enhanced versions of these commands, and puts them in a **Run `find` Command** menu, along with some other `find` commands.)

Comment: Well heck, that's even better.  How 'bout you post that as an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: Done.............